# Replacing <img> with <p> in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I went through a bunch of different questions here on stackoverflow but couldn't find the exact answer. I also went through the jQuery API and couldn't figure it out there either. So here's my problem .

```
<div id="click-nav">
   <ul>
       <li>
           <img src="img/pic.png">
                   <p>Some text and stuff</p>
       </li>
```

Then I have 3 more of the same situation but each p tag has different text. What I'm trying to do is replace the img tag with the p tag on hover for all 4 list items, and on hover each img is replaced with its corresponding p tag. Right now I have this as my jQuery, keep in mind I am pretty new to jQuery so I may have it all wrong.

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#click-nav p').hide();     //TO HIDE THE <P>
                        $("#click-nav img").hover(function () {    //FOR THE HOVER
                        $("#click-nav img").replaceWith('#click-nav p');
                    });
                });
</script>
```

So I never got to the roll off, I just wanted to figure out how to make the hover event work first, then I would get to the roll off. Hopefully that wasn't a giant jumbled mess. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: Not really a lot of information here to fully understand.. Please guide me through a user story upon using your feature.

Comment: I can make a jsfiddle, ill post a link soon

Comment: @bobeartow You really wanted to change or just hide the image and show the p instead?

Comment: @Ryanb58 Alright so basically upon arriving at this list, you would only see the img's and no paragraphs that come after the img's. When hovering over each image, the image would be replaced with the corresponding paragraph, and the img would be hidden. Once rolled off the paragraph would disappear and the image would show again.

Comment: @bobeartow  check my answer, the css part it will achieve what you just describe.  I also included an demo of it using only css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it like this.  Don't put the hover effect on the img because if the image is hidden the focus will be gone.

```
$("#click-nav ul li").hover(function () {   
     $(this).find('img').hide();
     $(this).find('p').show();
});
```

How ever doing it this way you need to make another function to reverse the effect when you hover out of it.

A better solution is to use CSS instead of jQuery

```
<style>
   #click-nav ul li:hover img {
       display: none;
   }
   #click-nav ul li:hover p {
       display: block;
   }
</style>
```

With css you don't need to worry about writing two scripts.

**[JSFIDDLE FOR CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/a7rsm6uL/)**

Comment: @RussellBevan what do you mean?  The css will only affect eh `<li>` that is currently being hovered.  You don't hover on multiple `<li>` at the same time right?

Comment: @RussellBevan I added a fiddle for the css check to see how it works, and enjoy. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This works! Can't believe I didn't try this first.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('img').on('onmouseover', function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).closest('p'));
});
```